# Input tag helper isn't allowing the usage of nameof()

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following ViewModel in my ASP.NET Core 1.1 application:

```
public class HomepageViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel mentioned above is used in a view with an input field like the one below.
As you can see, I'm trying to specify the asp-for property of the input tag helper by using nameof(), so that in case I rename the property in the ViewModel, the changes will also be applied to the view.

```
@model HomepageViewModel
[... various HTML Code...]

<input asp-for="@nameof(Model.Description)" class="form-control" />
```

In any case this isn't working since I receive the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException - Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Is there a way to use nameof() as I'm trying to do, or isn't it allowed for any specific reasons?

Comment: Even though it may look like just a string, it is in fact not just a string, and full Intellisense is provided for tag helper attributes like `asp-for`. That's the problem here actually: it's expecting a model expression (which provides the behavior you want) but it's instead getting a string.

Answer (score 1):

The `asp-for` is enough for a reference, a smart enough tool should detect those and rename appropriately.

For instance, I was able to rename a property using Resharper and it changed my view appropriately.

Comment: What I find strange with asp-for, however, is that I can put in an invalid property name for the asp-for value and I'll get a compile error (this is good).  However, for the asp-action tag helper, I can put in foo for the action name and I will *not* get a compiler error.  However, I can use nameof inside asp-action (ex: asp-action="@nameof(MyController.MyAction)" and it works fine.  So it's weird that nameof works inside some tag helpers and not others.